# Microsoft.Graph Create User Async gets stuck

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api

I use Microsoft Graph and actually everything works fine except creating users. Unfortunately, I do not get any error message. It just gets stuck in the "await". All other API calls work fine (delete user, create group, read user, etc.).

When I use the Graph Explorer, it works as well.

```vbnet
Dim AzureUser = New User With {
    .AccountEnabled = True,
    .DisplayName = Givenname & " " & Surname,
    .GivenName = Givenname,
    .Surname = Surname,
    .MailNickname = Givenname  & "." & Surname,
    .UserPrincipalName = Username,
    .PasswordProfile = New PasswordProfile With {
        .ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = False,
        .Password = MyPassword
        }
    }
Return Await GraphClient.Users.Request.AddAsync(AzureUser)
```

I tried it with the latest Microsoft Graph and Beta. I have the following "Microsoft Graph" application permissions:

- Directory.ReadWrite.All
- Domain.Read.All
- Group.ReadWrite.All
- TeamMember.ReadWrite.All
- User.ReadWrite.All

Usually when something doesn't work I get an error from the API but nothing happens. The user is created but it hangs.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: This sound like a dead lock. You can try `....AddAsync(AzureUser).ConfigureAwait(False)`. For more information : [ConfigureAwait FAQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/).

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that the user is created. Unfortunately, your suggestion does not bring any improvement.

Comment: I think it's callback that dead lock. You can encapsulate the call with `Task.Run`.